# Code optimisation cubic interpolation

Tags: python, optimization, numpy

I've been reading for quite some time Stack questions and answers and find a lot of very useful optimisation.
I'm kind of facing a bottleneck on the optimisation of the following code which is "just" for converting a cartesian map into a polar map. But with the particularity of increasing the density of angular points with the radius meaning that larger radius are described with more points.

Any idea to speed the process?

```
Rbin=440
Angbin=440
def cart2pol_alt(data,center,Rfact):

"""
Cubic interpolation
Fastest implementation of the cubic interpolation so far
Faster than max(0,(x+1)**3) by 20% or any of the factorization by bool (x+2>0) by 60-65%
"""
def cubic(x):
    p0=lambda y: (y+2)**3 if (y+2>0) else 0
    p1=lambda y: (y+1)**3 if (y+1>0) else 0
    p2=lambda y: (y)**3 if (y>0) else 0
    p3=lambda y: (y-1)**3 if (y-1>0) else 0
    return (p0(x)-4*p1(x)+6*p2(x)-4*p3(x))/6.

"""
Adapt the  selected area size to polar basis size
"""

rad=Rfact*np.concatenate([r*np.ones(2*r+1) for r in np.arange(Rbin)])
theta=np.concatenate([np.pi*np.arange(t)/t for t in 2*np.arange(Rbin)+1])
x=rad*np.cos(theta) + center[1]
y=-rad*np.sin(theta) + center[0]
#Cubic interpolation
ix=x.astype('int')
iy=y.astype('int')
dx=x-ix
dy=y-iy
polar=np.zeros_like(rad)

nX,nY=data.shape
for index in np.arange(Rbin*Angbin):
    for i in np.arange(-1,3):
        for j in np.arange(-1,3):
            condx=np.logical_and((ix[index]+i)<nX,(ix[index]+i)>=0)
            condy=np.logical_and((iy[index]+j)<nY,(iy[index]+j)>=0)
            if np.logical_and(condx,condy):
                cub=cubic(i-dx[index])*cubic(dy[index]-j)
                polar[index]+=data.ravel()[(ix[index]+i)*nY+(iy[index]+j)]*cub    

return polar
```

EDIT. Thanks all for your help. The vectorisation was not easy but i manage to reduce execution time from 4min to 2 s but using the following code. I hope it might help some people.

```
Rbin=440
Angbin=440
def cart2pol(data,scale,center,Rfact):

"""
    Cubic interpolation
    Fastest implementation of the cubic interpolation so far for an array
"""
def cubic(y):
    p0=(y+2)**3
        p0[p0<0]=0
        p1 = (y+1)**3
        p1[p1<0]=0
        p2 = y**3
        p2[p2<0]=0
        p3 =(y-1)**3
        p3[p3<0]=0
        return (p0-4.*p1+6.*p2-4.*p3)/6.

rad=Rfact*np.concatenate([r*np.ones(2*r+1) for r in np.arange(Rbin)])
theta=np.concatenate([np.pi*np.arange(t)/t for t in 2*np.arange(Rbin)+1])
x=rad*np.cos(theta) + center[1]
y=-rad*np.sin(theta) + center[0]
#Cubic interpolation
ix=x.astype('int')
iy=y.astype('int')
dx=x-ix
dy=y-iy
polar=np.zeros_like(rad)

i,j=np.meshgrid(np.arange(-1,3),np.arange(-1,3))
i=i.ravel()
j=j.ravel()
I,IX=np.meshgrid(i,ix)
J,IY=np.meshgrid(i,iy)
IXI=IX+I
IYJ=IY+J
    nX,nY=data.shape
rule1=(IXI<nX) & (IXI>=0)
rule2=(IYJ<nY) & (IYJ>=0)
cub=cubic(I-dx.reshape((dx.shape[0],1)))*cubic(dy.reshape((dy.shape[0],1))-J)
dat=data.ravel()[(IXI*nY+IYJ).ravel()].reshape(IYJ.shape)
polar+=(dat*cub).sum(axis=1)
return polar
```

If someone see additional optimisation, let me know!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow as a user then! To optimise your code probably is better [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). But as a start point I always try to avoid the for loops.

Comment: Can't you tabulate the function cubic uniformly on the useful range ? And what's the benefit of using lambda's here ? Also note that your interpolation scheme is separable.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably vectorize the for loops into something like:

```
nX,nY=data.shape
for i in np.arange(-1,3):
    for j in np.arange(-1,3):
        condx = np.logical_and((ix + i) < nX, (ix + i) >=0)
        condx = np.logical_and((iy + j) < nY, (iy + j) >=0)
        cub = cubic(i-dx) * cubic(dy - i)
        polar += data.ravel()[(ix + i) * nY + (iy + j)] * cub * \
                                     np.logical_and(condx, condy)
```

You can also remove if statements from the cubic function

```
def cubic(x):
    p0 = (y+2)**3
    p0[p0 < 0] = 0
    p1 = (y+1)**3
    p1[p1 < 0] = 0
    p2 = (y)**3
    p2[p2 < 0] = 0
    p3 = (y-1)**3
    p3[p3 < 0] = 0
    return (p0 - 4*p1 + 6*p2 - 4*p3) /6.
```

Comment: Thanks this cubic interpolation is indeed faster for arrays than the previous one

Answer (score 0):

I can't verify that it will produce the same result as your code since you haven't provided any data. But I would start with replacing one for-cycle with a vectorized operation.

```
for i in np.arange(-1, 3):
    ixi = ix+i
    condx = (ixi < nX) & (ixi >= 0)
    for j in np.arange(-1, 3):
        iyj = iy+j
        cond = (iyj < nY) & (iyj >= 0) & condx
        if cond.any():
            cub = cubic(i-dx[cond])*cubic(dy[cond]-j)
            polar[cond] += data[ixi[cond], iyj[cond]]*cub
```

Comment: Easy way to generate datas: X,Y=np.meshgrid(np.arange(-250,250),np.arange(-250,250)) and then datas=np.exp(-(sqrt(X**2+Y**2)-80)**2/50). That should give you a ring.

Comment: Yes, right. If I will understand your data I can produce them. However, you should provide a minimal working example when posting so that everyone who wants to help you doesn't have to come up with the same (or even worse - different) data. I am glad that you found a solution.